# Sum String and Integer

Tags: android, integer, sum

I have this:

For Example:

codincidenceSelected.id --> have value "1"

int one --> have value "1"

When i sum this integer and string it gives me "Incidence: 11", but I want "Incidence: 2", so my code it isn't summing, it is adding the value of the integer.

Here is my code:

```
 CodIncidence codIncidenceSelected = new CodIncidence();
        app = (netAppApplication)getApplicationContext();
        codIncidenceSelected = app.getcodincidenceActual(); 

        int one = 1;

        String total = codIncidenceSelected.id + one;


        Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this, "Incidence: " + total, 5000);
         toast.show();
```

Comment: your id is a string you should cast it to an integer: Integer.parseInt(codIncidenceSelected.id );

Comment: This is very basic question related to Java, not to android. It is good to start app development after learning the Java programming concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int total = Integer.parseInt(codIncidenceSelected.id) + one;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
String total = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(codIncidenceSelected.id) + one );
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work. The value of your `id` is a `String`. You must parse it as an `Integer` first to perform your calculation. Then taking the value of the `String` should parse it back to an `Integer`.

```
    int total = Integer.parseInt(codIncidenceSelected.id) + one;
    String answer = String.valueOf(total);

    Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this, "Incidence: " + answer, 5000);
         toast.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Change Following line

```
String total = codIncidenceSelected.id + one;
```

to

```
int total = Integer.parseInt(codIncidenceSelected.id) + one;
```

and then run your project.

Comment: You need cast the total to string in the toast

Comment: You're wrong because `Integer.parseInt(codIncidenceSelected.id) + one;` returns an integer, not a String. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i'm not an Android dev, but i think, first you need to make sure, that `total` is `int`, not `string`, then, transform `codIncidenceSelected.id` to `int`

UPD: oh, while I was writing you've already got answers how to do this )

Answer (score 0):

This is because Java is interpreting your `+` operator as a string concatenation.

If you want to sum the values then I suggest you do something like:

```
int total = codIncidenceSelected.id + one;

Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this, "Incidence: " + Integer.toString(total);, 5000);
toast.show();
```

This is of course assuming that `codIncidenceSelected.id` is a Java int. If it is a string then you will need to do:

```
int id = Integer.parseInt(codIncidenceSelected.id);
```

Before summing.

If you really only want to add the number 1 to the id then I also suggest you do something like the following:

```
int total = codIncidenceSelected.id++;
```

Again, assuming that `codIncidenceSelected.id` is an int (otherwise convert to int first as above).

Answer (score 0):

You should convert codIncidenceSelected to int first, and then sum them. try this method

```
Integer.parseInt(codIncidenceSelected).
```